# Elasticsearch cluster initializing - are imports happening?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 1.0.1.

I have a cluster with 1 index, 1 shard: 1 primary and 1 replica, 2 nodes.

The Elasticsearch cluster is yellow when I restart the entire cluster. The primary shards are started, but the replicas are still initializing, and will be green after they're done initializing. If an import is happening during this initialization phase, does the import replicate to the replicas during this phase? Or are they ONLY imported to the primary nodes?

(If the entire cluster is green, the import gets replicated of course, but I am not asking about this state).

Comment: Just for your info. Primary shards and replica shards have nothing to do with cluster. They are index specific. If your index has 1 primary and 1 replica shard, but you have only one node. Cluster health will always remain yellow.

Comment: Yes, you can assume my cluster has just 1 index here. and more than 1 node.

Comment: Can you check what is the sate of replica shard. Is it `unassigned` or `initilaizing`.

Comment: It's initializing. Not unassigned. I'm not one of THOSE questions.

Answer (score -2):

Elasticsearch cluster yellow means:

```
Elasticsearch has allocated all of the primary shards, but some/all of the replicas have not been allocated.
```

This happens when you do not have sufficient nodes to occupy all the shards(`replica shards`).

Read more [here](http://chrissimpson.co.uk/elasticsearch-yellow-cluster-status-explained.html)

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific. Are documents getting replicated to the replicas if an import happens during this yellow cluster state, and the replicas are being initialized?